# Home Router drawing wrong IP address

Tags: router, dhcp, wireless-access-point, bridge, ubiquiti

I have a house Netgear router (with an IP address for example `192.168.1.1`). I have an Ubiquity nanostation with a station and a access point going to a shop with a Linksys router there (with an IP address for example `192.168.1.12`).

This was all working until the power flashed, and now the problem I am having is that I can connect to the house router but it’s showing IP `192.168.1.12`. This is odd, because that IP is the shop IP, but the SSID is showing it’s the house. Any help?

Additional info.

- I have shop router a LAN to LAN and the DHCP is disabled
- I can see when logged into Netgear (home) router I can see that the Linksys (shop) router is wired there

Comment: This is a very vague description of your setup (probably also using the wrong terminology because "bridge" can mean multiple things in networking but none of them makes sense here) and doesn't tell us anything about your setup that helps us in diagnosing the problem. Please edit your question and add more info. It would help if you told us HOW you are connecting to the router. What brand and models are those routers and how are they wired together?

Comment: Did you set up Shop to Main as LAN to LAN and disable DHCP in Shop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you perhaps draw a diagram of your setup? It doesn't have to be beautiful or follow any conventions, but please include all relevant devices and connections between them.

Comment: SOLVED: so I had the ubiquity nanostation on the house set as the “station” and the shop set as “access point” turns out they need to be flipped around. Thanks for the input to keep me thinking on my toes

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution to your problem. Please add an answer below, then accept it 48 hours later (cooldown timer). If you do not want to write an answer, consider deleting the question.